# skip row 0 in CSV import

Tags: php, mysql, csv, upload

so I am uploading a CSV file to my mysql database and I want it to always skip the first line being line 0 which has the column names

the current code I use it

```
    //connect to the database 
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password"); 
    mysql_select_db("mydatabase",$connect); //select the table 
    // 

    if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

        //get the csv file 
        $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
        $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

        //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
        do { 
            if ($data[0]) { 
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES 
                    ( 
                        '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                        '".addslashes($data[2])."' 
                    ) 
                "); 
            } 
        } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
        // 

        //redirect 
        header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die; 

}
```

I need away to remove the following line
Source,First Name,Surname,Phone 1,Phone 2,Contact Email,Title,Ref Number,Date,Status

i was going to just do a `if($data[0]=="Source")` however the issue with this is what if they change the layout of the CSV file or something.

So my question is simple can we either skip the first row being row 0?

but if the row 0 first thing is not Source can I be alerted so I can look at the CSV file?

Comment: Put a variable to track iterations, and don't run the insert query if it's 0 or undefined.

Comment: [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) so much easier, and much faster than your approach, and it has a  setting for skipping the first row

Comment: If the file layout is changed then you'll need to revisit this code anyway. I wouldn't worry about it here unless you have a clear idea of what might happen.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested to try to use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE contacts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the first line of the file and discard it if it's a header line:

```
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    // read the first line
    $data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")
    // if the first line is a header, discard it and read the next
    if ($data[0] == "Source:") {
       $data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")
    }

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
    //
```

Incidentally, your `do...while` loop was around the wrond way as you originally had it. You were looking at the data before you'd read it. With the pre-reads I've added it should work.

Answer (score 0):

After fopen, I would call `fgets($handle);` and disregard the return value, thereby skipping the first line.